# Word 2003; footer has disappeared

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I have a document where the footer has disappeared.

I don't mean that the content has disappeared; if you do View | Header and Footer and then click the button to go to the footer, it doesn't display anything and the insertion point is still in the header.

If I add additional footers (e.g. by going into page layout and setting a different footer for the first page) then the first page footer appears, but not the one for the other pages (the "Primary Footer").

Comment: It's only happening with the one document? If you go into Print Layout or Full Screen Reading modes, does the footer show as expected?

Comment: Yeah.  But I have a fix - see the self-answer - I just wanted to get it written down, because I've seen it occasionally before and I can never google the answer.  I should be able to now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cracked this eventually. There was a problem with the document, clearly, but there is a fix:

- Put the document into Normal View (View | Normal)
- Fire up VBA (Alt + F11, or Tools | Macro | Visual Basic Editor)
- Bring up the "immediate" pane (CTRL + G or View | Immediate Window)

  `ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select`
- You're now in a slightly odd view of the footer. You can start
  putting things into the footer from here, and the normal views will
  come back to life.

Comment: It sounds like the footer was full of just "Null"?  Weird.. :) Cool you found that work-around, I'd up-vote but I'm out of votes for a few more hours. :)

Comment: Yeah, it didn't even have the End-Of-Story marker (the heavy underline in normal view; the terminal paragraph mark in print layout view).  But it would let me put content in.  Eventually, I messed about a bit more and the EOS marker appeared, but I don't quite know what I did (added a field and deleted it, I think).